# Swing/libgdx Level Editor

Tags: java, swing, libgdx

I am trying to build level editor for the game I'm making. What I want is to run the game in a Swing `JPanel`. Here is how I did that.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {       
    public GamePanel() {    
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
        canvas = new LwjglAWTCanvas(new MyGame());    
        add(canvas.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    }
}
```

So this is the problem. When I run MyGame as LwjglApplication it runs with about 60 fps.
But when I display it in JPanel it runs with more then 1000 fps and takes too much cpu.

Is there a way to fix that, so it would not use so much cpu. I don’t have much experience with Swing, should I be using something else.

Comment: I don't have much experience either, but here is somthing cool http://jmonkeyengine.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX has no framerate limits. It runs with the highest possible framerate. So you better have something like this in your main loop:

```
Thread.sleep((long)(1000/60-Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()));
```

You can change the 60 with your desired framerate and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desktop config to limit the framerate. For example:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = 
                new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.foregroundFPS = 60;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```